# Which password is required by hacker?

Tags: security, password

If there is a hacker wanting to access my local data from the Internet, do they need to enter my root password or power/normal user password? My OS is Lubuntu 20.4 with nearly default settings.

Comment: Your data or your server. Because ordinary user have own data (which can be interesting)

Comment: As long as you are using default repos, keeping all packages up to date and following security best practices, you should be mostly fine.

Comment: Ah, forget something to tell, that I try Lubuntu in livecd mode and in Virtualbox.

Answer (score 1):

Someone can compromise your server without knowing any of your passwords. They do so by running an exploit against one of the services running on your machine (e.g. a web server, or a SMB service) and obtaining a shell, either root or non-privileged. If it's a non-privileged shell they can do some privilege escalation to obtain root access. This is why it's important to

1. avoid running services you do not need
2. set a firewall and have it enable access only to the relevant ports
3. keep your machine up-to-date with the latest security updates and patches

Comment: But I'm asking when the hackers need passwords to enter my computer then which paswords they need.

Comment: Any account password might suffice.  Or not.  It depends how your system is configured.  But, generally, strangers knowing your password is always a bad thing.

Comment: Ah, forget something to tell, that I try Lubuntu in livecd mode and in Virtualbox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means a security expert, as far as I know it depends on how your computer got compromised. If you ran a malicious software as a user, it will probably have access to most of your $HOME and limited access to system depending on that user permissions and SELinux/AppArmor.

Even a userspace app has the potential to "elevate privileges" if your system has security vulnerabilities or bad config, which means it elevates to root without using a password by hijacking a legitimate vulnerable root process. (Or by other means)

As for passwords, if an admin user has his password compromised, it can be used to get root and have high privileges, same for root password.

Comment: I know how bad if a malware is installed to my computer, but as my repositories healthy it would happen only when a hacker enter my computer and do they want my passwords or usernames to achieve this?

Comment: Not necessarily, if your software has severe security flaws you can be "hacked" without any password. This depends on the attack surface you have, an internet facing server is at higher risk than your personal PC sitting behind NAT.

However always follow security best practices, better safe than sorry. @user533275

Comment: Ah, forget somthing to tell, that I try Lubuntu in livecd mode and in Virtualbox.

Comment: So it isn't installed on your computer. In this case you should worry a lot more about the vulnerabilities of your installed os instead of one isolated in a VM or running temporarily off a livecd. @user533275

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm going to assume that there is a path from the Internet to your system that requires a normal login. That would normally be `ssh`, but there are other possibilities. Of course, if you are concerned about hackers logging in, you will not expose such access to the Internet.

The answer is simple: if a hacker has *your* username/password, he can access *your* data. The system does not differentiate between people using the same userid/password combinations.
If the hacker has the password of `root` and you allow root to log-in directly , then the hacker has access to all data on the system, not only yours.